# Assign global variable to field in related table

Tags: arcpad

I'm able to get ESRI's [ArcPad Login Form](http://arcpadteam.blogspot.ca/2009/07/arcpad-login-form.html) to assign a global variable to a field in the EDITFORM for Page1, but I actually want it to assign to a field in a related table (TABLEFORM), using an onload event.

The code below works to access the EDITFORM:

> Dim pForm
>   Set pForm = ThisEvent.Object
>
> pForm.Pages("Page1").Controls("txtUser").Value =
>   Application.UserProperties("LoggedInEmployee")

But I can't seem to find any documentation on how to access a related table using the same method.  This [forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/22638-Help-on-lt-TABLEFORM-gt-element) touches on my issue, but doesn't answer it.

Any help/advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

The trick was to access the object controls directly on the tableform using an onload event.
The first step is to create a custom form for the related table, and then click the page properties > events.... create an onload event (if applicable to your application), and enter the following lines of code:

> Dim objPage, objControls
>
> Set objPage = ThisEvent.Object
>   Set objControls = objPage.Controls
>
> objPage.Controls("Combo1").Value =
>   Application.UserProperties("LoggedInEmployee")

Note: "Combo1" is the name of the combo box I'm populating using the global variable created using [ESRI's login form](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16477).